# Why do I fail to set this range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to define a range in VBA, but for some reason my method fails. In the code sample below, the two first lines work, but the last one fails with the message "*Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed*":

```
Set c = Parametre.Range("B2")
Set c = Parametre.Range("XFD2").End(xlToLeft)
Set c = Range(Parametre.Range("B2"), Parametre.Range("XFD2").End(xlToLeft))
```

I've checked that the sheet isn't protected, that the second argument is to the right of the first one (it's L2), and am at the moment pretty stumped as to why my method fails. Any input on what may be the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming `Parametre` is a `worksheet` object, your code is perfectly valid. I copy+pasted it and it works fine, even if `Parametre` is not the Active worksheet.

Comment: Yeah, that was my assumption too, as this normally works, in my experience. Can't quite figure out what makes this instance different from normal. @Kyle

Answer (score 2):

You seem to miss the Parametre object, so it will default back to Worksheet, and fails for that reason. Try to use the following code:

```
Set c = Parametre.Range(Parametre.Range("B2"), Parametre.Range("XFD2").End(xlToLeft))
```

or alternatively if you want to write more cleaner code, use this:

```
with Parametre
    Set c = .Range("B2")
    Set c = .Range("XFD2").End(xlToLeft)
    Set c = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Range("XFD2").End(xlToLeft))
end with
```

Comment: The object exists though: http://i.imgur.com/6USk9fn.png And if it fails because it defaults back to worksheet, shouldn't the first two instances fail too? Quite apart from that, I think that your third declaration will fail because of an invalid function-call.

Comment: You write `parametre.range` for the first two, and the third one, you only write `range`. VBA is not smart enough to understand range, and tries to apply this to the worksheet object and fails. Try it and you'll see that it works.

Comment: @eirikdaude This is correct, though I'm not entirely sure what the code is doing in the first place.